# VPS can ping host by IP but not by name

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, subdomain, ping, troubleshooting

My Debian VPS `can ping all host by name and IP` but there's one host I can't ping by name.

Ping by name failed but successful with IP
[image]

However on my home PC i can ping that host by name and IP.

[image]

I flushed the DNS on my home PC to make sure I don't use cached record. What is the problem here? Thanks in advance.

Update with `dig +trace ns1.imagihost.com` output:
[image]

Comment: To avoid guessing, please post the output of "dig +trace ns1.imagihost.com". That command should trace (and show) your DNS request to that host.

Comment: @Pedro Perez I have included the requested information.

Comment: Andrew B just left a great answer :) thanks for the quick turnaround, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy: Because you didn't define an `A` record for it.

A `dig +trace +additional ns1.imagihost.com A` shows us your nameservers, the glue records, and the output from a nameserver responsible for `imagihost.com`:

```
imagihost.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns2.altairhost.com.
imagihost.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns1.altairhost.com.
ns2.altairhost.com.     172800  IN      A       104.206.190.110
ns1.altairhost.com.     172800  IN      A       104.206.190.110
;; Received 114 bytes from 192.54.112.30#53(192.54.112.30) in 124 ms

imagihost.com.          86400   IN      SOA     ns1.altairhost.com. premiumicloud.icloud.com. 2015022103 86400 7200 3600000 86400
;; Received 107 bytes from 104.206.190.110#53(104.206.190.110) in 64 ms
```

To reinforce the point:

```
# dig @104.206.190.110 ns1.imagihost.com | grep status
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 33294
```

As for why that works on your home PC after a cache purge, it suggests you've defined this record on your home network somehow. We can't tell you whether this is a private DNS server that you run, something that was added to your hosts file, or whether your ISP had the record cached still from when it used to be there. It's your home network: the fact that it resolves there is not really a problem we're going to speculate about on Serverfault.

If you want to address the internet visibility problem, you need to define the missing `ns1.imagihost.com. IN A` record in DNS. If you want to find out why it still resolves on your home network, you've got some more research to do and that's not something we can help you with.

---

Also, here's a freebie: `ns1.altairhost.com` and `ns2.altairhost.com` are both pointing at the same IP address. This is an *incredibly* unsafe DNS configuration that is going to create unpredictable problems with your domain availability. Each nameserver should be a different DNS server, and those servers should not be located at the same datacenter. Even the *briefest* of network problems between anyone on the internet and that one IP address is going to cause your domain to briefly vanish from the internet for some people.

Comment: I don't get NXDOMAIN. I get port unreachable from 104.206.190.110. (I even tried from three different networks.)

Comment: Then 104.206.190.110 is a sick name server, and further indicates the need for a second NS.  When it's up though, it shows there is a record for imagihost.com (pointing to itself), but gives NXDOMAIN for ns1.imagihost.com.  Possibly it did exist within the last few hours and is cached on your ISP's name server, but I'd check your c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts file to avoid one possible source of confusion.

Comment: My ISP DNS cached is the problem. I test it by using google DNS on my home PC network properties and I could not resolve the subdomain. Change back to my ISP DNS and I can ping the subdomain. Thank you very much for your help.